# vagrant ssh responded with with a non-zero

Tags: bash, ssh, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile

I am using vagrant on windows 8.1 and when I am doing `vagrant up` I am getting [this error](http://screencast.com/t/HwOa7iM9Co0)

The error message states that it failed trying execute this command:

```
chown `id -u vagrant`:`id -g vagrant` /vagrant
```

So I accessed the host machine by ssh: and I tried to execute the same command and I [get error](http://screencast.com/t/I8QIESl8Q4)

Here is [some commands](http://screencast.com/t/K3lT1rE8Tkl) I tried to execute in /vagrant directory, I don't know if that will help.

Here is my [vagrantFile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms4qw7rq5qq2sgb/Vagrantfile?dl=0) that I am using.

Please any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Semi-wild guess here, but I think the mount is acting up. The directory exists, but can't read/set any properties. What is it mounted as? `mount | grep vagrant`

Comment: Take a look to this [thread](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5933). Seems to be fixed on [this commit](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4815).

Comment: @Anonymous I get this `vagrant on /vagrant type vboxsf (uid=1000,gid=1000,rw)` by executing what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

/vagrant probably doesn't exist

Check for /home/projects

This line in your Vagrantfile sets that directory.  ./projects is on the host, /home/projects is on the guest.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./projects", "/home/projects", nfs: true
```